# How do I right align the check box in my Java SWT application

Tags: java, checkbox, alignment, swt

How do I right align the check box in my `Java SWT` application ? Here is my code snippet:

```
    Button checkFullECR = new Button(scrolledForm.getBody(), SWT.CHECK);
    checkFullECR.setAlignment(SWT.RIGHT);
    checkFullECR.setBackground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_WHITE));
    checkFullECR.setText("I need the complete ECR/ECN Process:");
```

It looks like the following:

```
[ ] I need the complete ECR/ECN Process:
```

I want it to look like:

```
I need the complete ECR/ECN Process:       [ ]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do this using just a `Button` control, you will need to use a `Label` for the text and a checkbox `Button` with no text arranged in two columns.

Something like:

```
Composite body = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);

body.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, false));

Label label = new Label(body, SWT.LEFT);
label.setText("I need the complete ECR/ECN Process:");

Button checkFullECR = new Button(body, SWT.CHECK);

... more label / button pairs ....
```

Answer (score 5):

For once I kind of have to disagree with Greg.

You can use the `setOrientation(int)` method of the `Button` to force right-to-left layout:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new GridLayout());

    Button button = new Button(shell, SWT.CHECK);
    button.setText("TEST");

    button = new Button(shell, SWT.CHECK);
    button.setOrientation(SWT.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
    button.setText("TEST");

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();

    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
        {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }

    display.dispose();
}
```

Looks like this:

[image]

(**Tested on Linux Mint and Windows. Does not work on the Mac.**)

Comment: Converted from non-answer: The button.setOrientation() method is not available in Eclipse 3.6.2... used the button- label combination

Comment: @Baz Good catch, however when writing I18N applications, the ```SWT.RIGHT_TO_LEFT``` is used for Locale specific formatting. One would have to specifically exclude check boxes from toggling the text direction when switching to a right to left language (Locale).